# Group by hours and minutes without multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a data frame with two columns. 'Login_time' is punch in times in datetime. The times are separated by 15 minutes and the range is over 30 years. The second column is 'counted' which is the amount of times people punched in during the interval.

| login_time | counted |
| --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 20:00:00 | 2 |
| 1970-01-01 20:15:00 | 6 |

I want to count how many people clocked in at all time intervals during the year.

| interval | total punches |
| --- | --- |
| 20:00:00 | 3008 |
| 20:15:00 | 42000 |

I tried the following:

```
df_grouped = df2.groupby([df2['login_time'].dt.hour, df2['login_time'].dt.minute]).counted.sum()
```

It kind of works but I get a multi index with the hour being one index and the minute intervals.

is it possible to get it like I have it above? or at least to unit the indices into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping by `dt.hour` and `dt.minute`, simply group by [`dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'login_time': {0: pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01 20:00:00'),
                       1: pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01 20:15:00'),
                       2: pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 20:00:00'),
                       3: pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 20:15:00')},
        'counted': {0: 2, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 6}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_grouped = (df.groupby(df['login_time'].dt.time)['counted']
              .sum()
              .reset_index()
              .rename(columns={'login_time': 'interval', 'counted': 'total punches'}))

df_grouped

   interval  total punches
0  20:00:00              4
1  20:15:00             12
```